# Check if mail address exists on sending mail through AWS SES + Spring Boot

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, email

I´m trying to send a test mail through AWS SES using Java + Spring Boot, like the example:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-java.html

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class AmazonSESSample {

    // Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address.
    // This address must be verified.
    static final String FROM = "sender@example.com";
    static final String FROMNAME = "Sender Name";

    // Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account 
    // is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
    static final String TO = "recipient@example.com";

    // Replace smtp_username with your Amazon SES SMTP user name.
    static final String SMTP_USERNAME = "smtp_username";

    // Replace smtp_password with your Amazon SES SMTP password.
    static final String SMTP_PASSWORD = "smtp_password";

    // The name of the Configuration Set to use for this message.
    // If you comment out or remove this variable, you will also need to
    // comment out or remove the header below.
    static final String CONFIGSET = "ConfigSet";

    // Amazon SES SMTP host name. This example uses the Oeste dos EUA (Oregon) region.
    // See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html#region-endpoints
    // for more information.
    static final String HOST = "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";

    // The port you will connect to on the Amazon SES SMTP endpoint. 
    static final int PORT = 587;

    static final String SUBJECT = "Amazon SES test (SMTP interface accessed using Java)";

    static final String BODY = String.join(
            System.getProperty("line.separator"),
            "<h1>Amazon SES SMTP Email Test</h1>",
            "<p>This email was sent with Amazon SES using the ", 
            "<a href='https://github.com/javaee/javamail'>Javamail Package</a>",
            " for <a href='https://www.java.com'>Java</a>."
        );

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Create a Properties object to contain connection configuration information.
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        // Create a Session object to represent a mail session with the specified properties. 
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

        // Create a message with the specified information. 
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM,FROMNAME));
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(TO));
        msg.setSubject(SUBJECT);
        msg.setContent(BODY,"text/html");

        // Add a configuration set header. Comment or delete the 
        // next line if you are not using a configuration set
        msg.setHeader("X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET", CONFIGSET);

        // Create a transport.
        Transport transport = session.getTransport();

        // Send the message.
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Sending...");

            // Connect to Amazon SES using the SMTP username and password you specified above.
            transport.connect(HOST, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);

            // Send the email.
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            System.out.println("Email sent!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("The email was not sent.");
            System.out.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close and terminate the connection.
            transport.close();
        }
    }
}
```

When I use

```
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
```

I´ve got "Could not connect to SMTP host: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, port: 25" or "530 Authentication required" in other implementations.

When I use

```
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
```

It sends the e-mail, but looks like it doesn´t check if the address really exists. To test it, I changed the destination address to:

```
static final String TO = "fds7yf7dsyf7ysyf7ddsf@gmail.com";
```

This is an e-mail that doesn´t exists and my class didn´t return any error or exception. Is that normal? Shouldn´t it validate this address and return an error in this case? If yes, how can I get this error since the try/catch isn´t doing that?

Thanks

Comment: Delivery failure is usually handled by the destination handler sending an Failed Message Undeliverable message back to your from e-mail address IIRC.

Comment: SMTP servers don't verify whether an email address exists. That is up to the receiving server. You probably want a service like kickbox.com instead.

Comment: As a general rule, an SMTP server will not report an error if an email address does not exist. The reason is that you could run a dictionary attack against an email server to determine valid email addresses. Another reason is that the SMTP server you are connecting to may be a "forwarder"and does not hold the actual email mailbox, so it would not know if an email address exists.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys, very useful answers =)

Comment: Perhaps this would help you out. https://serverfault.com/questions/925346/how-to-add-amazons-x-ses-configuration-setconfigset-to-a-my-postfix-mail-serve